# Passing a method vs. passing an interface in Kotlin

Tags: oop, kotlin

When I use Java, it's easy to use interface to send method to another class. And it's good in OOP way:

```
class A{
   private FooListener listener;

   public A(FooListener listener){
        this.listener = listener;
   }

   public void foo(){
        // do something
        listener.method();
   }
}
```

But in Kotlin, we can easily pass the method using parameter like this:

```
class A(val method: () -> Unit ) {
    fun foo(){ 
        // do something
        method()
    }
}
```

is that code is still good in OOP way? or i should use interface? i think its ok to pass the method directly.

Comment: Passing a function is more readable than creating an interface, possibly creating and an anonymous class. Either way, it's a good approach.

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin both of these methods are correct and can be used depending on your use case. 
Unlike Java which was primarily an [Object Oriented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) language but later included some [functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) programming features with the introduction of java 8, Kotlin from beginning is designed to support both [Object Oriented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) as well as [functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) approach.

as [Kotlin in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/kotlin-in-action) states

> Kotlin lets you program in the functional style but doesn’t enforce
>   it.
>
> When you need it, you can work with mutable data and write
>   functions that have side effects without jumping through any extra
>   hoops. And, of course, working with frameworks that are based on
>   interfaces and class hierarchies is just as easy as with Java.
>
> **When
>   writing code in Kotlin, you can combine both the object-oriented and
>   functional approaches and use the tools that are most appropriate for
>   the problem you’re solving.**

Answer (score 0):

The code is OK. It's better to write more readable code than a "this must be OOP" code.